# Gatsby StaticQuery Not Returning A Value

Tags: graphql, gatsby

On my index.js I would like to show a number of components, each self-contained with their own queries etc.. I am using Gatsby's code from their static-query docs page. However, nothing is being returned, at all. I get no errors, on building the development bundle, or in the console. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, please?

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

export default function Segment() {
return (
    <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
            query {
                allSanityProduct(limit:1) {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            productName
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        `}
        render={data => (
            <header>
                <h1>{data.allSanityProduct.edges.productName}</h1>
            </header>
        )}
    />
)
}
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: IMHO works as expected, renders nothing for undefined ... bad data path/selector

Answer (score 1):

The correct data path should be:

```
data.allSanityProduct.edges[0].node.productName
```